# PHP pcntl module installation

Tags: php, html, apache, debian

I'm trying to install the pcntl module into php for Debian.

What i did so fat :

- Apache installation

  ```
  apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert
  ```
- PHP installation

  ```
  apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-ming php5-mysql php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
  ```
- Compilling pcntl

  ```
  cd php
  apt-get source php5
  cd php5-(WHATEVER_RELEASE)/ext/pcntl
  phpize
  ./configure
  make
  ```

But when a run the "Make test"  i got someting like that :

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pcntl.so' in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pcntl.so' in Unknown on line 0
```

Am I missing something here????

So after that, i know that i need to rebuild PHP with the follow command :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-sysvsem --enable-pcntl --enable-sigchild
make
make install
```

And i have the same warning when i start my apache server.
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add the new extension to your php.ini.

```
extension=pcntl.so
```

---

Edit:
Look at this answer, someone else had the same problem as you before: [php startup error Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pcntl.so'](https://superuser.com/a/485750/414500)

Comment: yes of cource, i did that after building my own php. But i still have the same issue

Comment: @gabsao I have edited my answer. Have a look at it. I think you have to change a directory.